# Calculate second highest cumulative value by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have data with a grouping variable 'grps' and a value 'x'. I have calculated the `cummax` within each group 'cmx'. Now I need to find the *second* highest cumulative value of 'x' within each group, `scmx`.

Some data, including the desired column `scmx`:

```
library(data.table)
d = structure(list(date = structure(rep(c(18690, 18691, 18692, 18693, 18694, 18695, 18696, 18697), 2), class = "Date"),
                   x = c(18, 70, 57, 94, 94, 13, 98, 23, 20, 72, 59, 96, 96, 15, 100, 25),
                   grps = c(rep("g1", 8), rep("g2", 8))),
              row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
d[, cmx := cummax(x), by = .(grps)]
d[, scmx := c(18, 18, 57, 70, 70, 70, 94, 94, 20, 20, 59, 72, 72, 72, 96, 96)]
```

---

#### Context

If `x` corresponds to a performance rating, what I am trying to do is locate the date when they achieved their best performance and their second best. A similar question of mine where I needed to locate the row which corresponded to the highest cumulative value in a column:

[Fill down first row within each cumulative max, with a twist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472599/fill-down-first-row-within-each-cumulative-max-with-a-twist/66479411?noredirect=1#comment117649792_66479411)

Comment: Seems related: [Finding cumulative second max per group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538324/finding-cumulative-second-max-per-group-in-r)

Comment: @Henrik Thanks I didn't see that one. I was hoping for a `data.table` type solution though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` alternative:

```
d[ , scmx2 := {
  c(x[1], sapply(seq(.N)[-1], function(i){
    v = x[1:i]
    v[frank(-v, ties.method = "dense") == 2][1]
  }))
}, by = grps]

#           date   x grps cmx scmx scmx2
#  1: 2021-03-04  18   g1  18   18    18
#  2: 2021-03-05  70   g1  70   18    18
#  3: 2021-03-06  57   g1  70   57    57
#  4: 2021-03-07  94   g1  94   70    70
#  5: 2021-03-08  94   g1  94   70    70
#  6: 2021-03-09  13   g1  94   70    70
#  7: 2021-03-10  98   g1  98   94    94
#  8: 2021-03-11  23   g1  98   94    94
#  9: 2021-03-04  20   g2  20   20    20
# 10: 2021-03-05  72   g2  72   20    20
# 11: 2021-03-06  59   g2  72   59    59
# 12: 2021-03-07  96   g2  96   72    72
# 13: 2021-03-08  96   g2  96   72    72
# 14: 2021-03-09  15   g2  96   72    72
# 15: 2021-03-10 100   g2 100   96    96
# 16: 2021-03-11  25   g2 100   96    96
```

---

Within each group (`by = grps`), loop (`sapply`) over a sequence from 2 to number of rows in the current group (`seq(.N)[-1]`). In each step, subset 'x' from start of the vector to the index 'i' (`v = x[1:i]`).

Calculate dense rank and check if the rank is 2 (`frank(-v, ties.method = "dense") == 2`), i.e. the rank of the second largest number. Use the logical indices to subset 'v' (`v[...`). Select the first match (`[1]`; in case of several values with rank 2). Concatenate the result from this 'expanding window' with the first element of 'x' (`c(x[1], ...`).

---

In the first window, with only one value, there is clearly no second highest value. Here OP have chosen to return the first value. The same choice needs to be made also for longer windows where all values are equal, which will occur when there are leading runs of equal values. If we rather want to return `NA` than the first value, then replace the `x[1]` in the line

```
c(x[1], sapply(seq(.N)[-1], function(i){
```

...with `NA_real_`.

Small demo:

```
d = data.table(grps = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2), x = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 5)) 

d[ , scmx2 := {
  c(NA_real_, sapply(seq(.N)[-1], function(i){
    v = x[1:i]
    v[frank(-v, ties.method = "dense") == 2][1]
  }))
}, by = grps]

#    grps x scmx
# 1:    1 3   NA # grp 1: all values equal in all windows -> all NA
# 2:    1 3   NA
# 3:    2 4   NA
# 4:    2 4   NA  
# 5:    2 5    4 # grp 2: only the last window has a second highest value
```

---

This question is indeed similar to the post I linked to above ([Finding cumulative second max per group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64538324/finding-cumulative-second-max-per-group-in-r)). However, here OP asked for a `data.table` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using non-equi join:

```
d[, s2 := .SD[.SD, on=.(grps, date<=date, x<cmx), by=.EACHI, max(x.x)]$V1]
d[is.na(s2), s2 := x][]
```

output:

```
          date   x grps cmx scmx s2
 1: 2021-03-04  18   g1  18   18 18
 2: 2021-03-05  70   g1  70   18 18
 3: 2021-03-06  57   g1  70   57 57
 4: 2021-03-07  94   g1  94   70 70
 5: 2021-03-08  94   g1  94   70 70
 6: 2021-03-09  13   g1  94   70 70
 7: 2021-03-10  98   g1  98   94 94
 8: 2021-03-11  23   g1  98   94 94
 9: 2021-03-04  20   g2  20   20 20
10: 2021-03-05  72   g2  72   20 20
11: 2021-03-06  59   g2  72   59 59
12: 2021-03-07  96   g2  96   72 72
13: 2021-03-08  96   g2  96   72 72
14: 2021-03-09  15   g2  96   72 72
15: 2021-03-10 100   g2 100   96 96
16: 2021-03-11  25   g2 100   96 96
```

Comment: I tried pecking on the upvote, but it only allowed one. Thanks for sharing, really nice!

Comment: thanks @Henrik!. I think your solution is more robust as it can select any top nth value :)

Comment: Perhaps robust, but that's a poor consolation when elegance is key.

Comment: We are all hungry for interesting questions hahaha

Comment: @chinsoon12 this is considerably quicker than the solution above. This takes 7 seconds vs. 450 for the method by Henrik.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence that is the length of the column `x`. Apply the function to each sequence in `x` that is from index 1 to the current number in the sequence, only caring about the unique values. `Rfast::nth` can be used to take the 2nd highest number in a vector.

```
library(Rfast)
sapply(seq(length(d$x)), function(x) {
  return(nth(unique(d$x[1:x]), 2, descending=TRUE))
})

[1] 2.652495e-315  1.800000e+01  5.700000e+01  7.000000e+01
[5]  7.000000e+01  7.000000e+01  9.400000e+01  9.400000e+01
```

To do it for the new data frame. We can still use the function created above. Arrange the data frame so that the group names and values are in their own column, then use `lapply` with `rollapplyr` to capture the 2nd largest unique value.

```
d1=d %>% select(-cmx) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=grps, values_from=x)
lapply(d1[-1], function(x) {
  my_list=rollapplyr(x, seq(length(x)), function(x) {return(nth(sort(unique(x), decreasing=TRUE), 2))})
  return(my_list)
})
```

Comment: Apologies, I need this within groups so I have updated my question. This worked well otherwise.